# Ask and wait for some widget's data

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am often faced with the situation where a widget needs data which is contained or can be obtained by another widget, and I don't know how to handle that.
My unsatisfactory workaround:

```
class DataWidget(...):
    data = pyqtSignal(...)
    ...
    def asked_for_data(self):
        self.data.emit(self._data)

class ProcessWidget(...):
    ask_for_data = pyqtSignal()
    ...
    def working_hard(self):
        ...
        # I need the data from my widget friend
        self.ask_for_data.emit()
        # but I need it here :(

    def got_data(self, data):
        # and I got it here...

class App(...):
    def __init__(self):
        data_widget = DataWidget()
        self._data_widget = data_widget
        process_widget = ProcessWidget()
        self._proces_widget = process_widget
        process_widget.ask_for_data.connect(data_widget.asked_for_data)
        data_widget.data.connect(process_widget.got_data)
```

Is there something more direct in the style of:

```
def working_hard(self):
    ...
    data = ask_for_data.exec()
```

with `ask_for_data` being some sort of event class.

Comment: "a widget needs data which is contained or can be obtained by another widget": those are two very different things. If you're talking about some possibly long processing in the second case, then you should probably prefer using threading (through QThread). In the other case, the logic is wrong, as signals are not intended to be callback with return values: you shouldn't use a signal to get data, just find a way to create a persistent reference from the widget that needs data to the one that will provide it.

Comment: @musicamente ok I see. I face both cases, and for the first one you are right, the logic was wrong. For the second case, I need some QThread reading... Thanks.